# Prinft line by line of file single thread C

Tags: c, multithreading, file, line-by-line

I'm very stuck with one single problem, I need prinft file's line one by one in order with one thread. This is the code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <string.h>
    /* Prototypes */

    pthread_t reader;

    void *readLine(void *line)
    {   
        printf("Thread: %s \n",(char*)line);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE * fp;
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;



        fp = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);



        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)   {

            if(pthread_create(&reader, NULL, readLine, (void *)line)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");         
            }

        }


        fclose(fp);
        if  (line)
            free(line);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

This code print lines in disorder and no all thread are print the line passed by readLine, how can I print line by line by the same thread reader?

Comment: Why would you be using `pthread` if all you have to do is print the lines one by one? I'm pretty sure that if you spawn a bunch of threads and the job of each is to print a single line, some of the threads are going to finish execution "out of order".

Comment: It would help if you didn't pass the same line buffer to all of them. Think about it - what if you start the thread, then you read the next line into the same buffer, THEN the thread calls `printf`?

Comment: i just one part of the work, but the principal is pass line by thread to another threads.

Comment: In addition to what immibis said, if you want anything to happen in a certain order in a multi-threaded environment then you need explicit synchronisation. It's not clear exactly how you want your program to behave. But one way to serialise the output is to call `pthread_join` after the `pthread_create` to wait for the thread to complete its work. The result is a pretty useless program as the same could be done more efficiently without threading. But it will produce output in the right order.

Comment: kaylum - :O Thanks! i already put ptrhead_join (but i think, not in the right position), with pthrad_join after create work perfectly. TY

Answer (score 2):

Basically, by using independent threads, you are sending them all on their way independently, and they might pass each other.

Imagine you send *twenty* people independently to run to Starbucks and get a coffee - depending on their driving and route choices, they will arrive in *any* order, not repeatable, and not in the order you sent them.

To stay in the example, just send *one* guy to get twenty coffees, and you will be good.

Comment: *Imagine you send twenty people independently to run to Starbucks and get a coffee - depending on their driving and route choices, they will arrive in any order, not repeatable, and not in the order you sent them.*  And in this case, you drive off before they come back.